# DAO with Null Object Pattern

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, dao, null-object-pattern

**After Reading:**  
Effective Java (See Item 43) - Joshua Bloch 
Clean Code (Don't Return Null) - Uncle Bob 
[Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements?rq=1) 
[Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

I was looking for an answer to the question of what a DAO should return when a search ends up to be for an entity that does not exist for non-collection objects.
Collection object is really ok by using empty array or emptyList methods. But with non-collections it might be harder. An alternative solution is to never return null and instead use the Null Object pattern.
But I have no idea to integrate with Null Object pattern with DAO and I really excited to see great integration with Null Object pattern and DAO pattern especially for model(dto) object return case.

I would appreciate and welcome any best design pattern, scenario and suggestion.

Comment: Could returning an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) be helpful?

Comment: You could also throw an exception if you're that set on not using null.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, ya, but i come across from this  https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-avoid-null-and ,as to comments it's not best practice yet and Null Object Pattern is still best idea.

Comment: @chrylis, I expect for the case where null is a valid response in terms of the contract; and

Comment: NullObject pattern is returning an object that matches the signature of your populated object (user) with an object that the rest of the code can determine that a null object would have been returned (EmptyUser). The whole idea behind it is that object.getName() will never return null but instead return some entry that you can check ie if(user.getName().equals("e'); drop table Students;") then //we have empty object (or in this case little Bobby drop tables)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indeed introducing `null` reference is probably one of the worse mistake in the programming languages' history even its creator [**Tony Hoare**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) calls it his *billion-dollar mistake*.

Here are the best alternatives to `null` according to your `Java` version:

#### 1. `Java 8` and above

Starting from **Java 8**  you can use [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

*Here is an example of how you could use it in your case:*

```
public Optional<MyEntity> findMyEntity() {
    MyEntity entity = // some query here
    return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
}
```

#### 2. Prior to `Java 8`

Before **Java 8** you can use [`com.google.common.base.Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) from **Google Guava**.

*Here is an example of how you could use it in your case:*

```
public Optional<MyEntity> findMyEntity() {
    MyEntity entity = // some query here
    return Optional.fromNullable(entity);
}
```

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-avoid-null-and , I come across this website about Optional but your example is exceptionally good. I would like to know that do you prefer Optional than the Null Object Pattern for null handling case?

Comment: Yes I definitively prefer `Optional` it is much more generic and it has been adopted by Oracle and Google, 2 of the biggest IT companies in the world which give a lot of credits to it. I would even say that `Null Object Pattern` doesn't make any sense anymore in java, it is outdated, `Optional` is the future if you check a little bit what's new in Java 9, you will see that Oracle makes `Optional` go a little bit further, read [this](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/java-9-optional/)

Comment: The use of Optional, says that the cardinality of the return value is 0 or 1. So it gives a clear description that there could be no value and let the caller decide what to do with it

Comment: This is so useful, but i was wondering if we should use Optional in DAO layers too? I mean the return value, should it be Optional<Something>? or should it be in higher layers like services? and by the way how about restful services return value?

Comment: @Shilan my answer is simply why not having it in your DAO interface?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto exactly, when i have these three layers, DAO, Service, Controller(restfuls), should i just place it in DAO layer? is it the right solution? I agree with you :)

Comment: @Shilan it is a pure design choice, but IMHO if you consider an interface as a contract between the implementations and their consumers, it would be more obvious to understand that a value could be absent if you return `Optional<Something>` instead of returning directly `Something` that could be `null` even if it is specified in the javadoc. The clearer would be your interface, the better it would be.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is return an empty object - say a customer entry you would have in your DAO something like

if (result == null) { return new EmptyUser(); }

where EmptyUser extends User and returns appropriate entries to getter calls to allow the rest of your code to know it is an empty object (id = -1 etc)

**A small example**

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    public String getName() {
       //Code here
    }
    public void setName() {
       //Code here
    }
}

public class EmptyUser extends User {

    public int getId() {
       return -1;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return String.Empty();
   }
}

public User getEntry() {
   User result = db.query("select from users where id = 1");
   if(result == null) {
       return new EmptyUser();
   }
   else {
       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's null object pattern for this case but could you please provide some pattern diagram and provide full code for EmptyUser(NullObject) class? assume 10 fields had in EmptyUser class.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, in real-life scenarios where a single entity should be returned returning a null is actually either a data inconsistency error or lack of data whasoever. In both cases the *really* good thing to do is to crate and throw your own `DataNotFoudException`. **Fail fast**.

I'm using mybatis as ORM and recently I started writing some theoretically single-result mapper selects as returning lists and validating checking the amount of returned data in dao, and throwing exceptions when the returned amounts do not match dao's method assumptions. It works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sometimes  I expect for the case where null is a valid response, for this case I want to control with custom message and some navigation to users. Especially in combo-box value display and it master setup case.

Comment: Throwing an exception is still an option. You can catch it anywhere in your stack. But that's for abnormal situations only, so if you really expect your query to return null, then simply go with null or Optional.